WKWebview can't play mp3 sound
My WKWebView cannot play MP3 sound. The play and pause of my MP3 are controlled by a remote signal. I'm not sure if this has triggered the restriction that audio playback must be initiated by user interaction, but the following situations seem to conflict with this restriction:

My built-in WKWebView plays web page MP3s without sound on device A, but plays them with sound on device B.
If I use WKWebView to load other third-party websites and click to play MP3, device A also has sound.
I use WKWebView's loadFileURL method to load web pages.

anyone know the root cause?
ps: there are more than one devices act like device A, and device A speaker work well for other website and app.
